# CAT Transitions with a UITabBar and a NavigationController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, core-graphics, quartz-core

Not sure whats happening here.

When I do this in a Action to show another viewController:

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction  functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.type =  @"cube";
transition.subtype = @"fromRight";
[self.navigationController.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

forgotLoginViewController = [[ForgotLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ForgotLoginViewController" bundle:Nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:forgotLoginViewController animated:YES];
```

its not working. However when I do...(Add subview to the view)

```
CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction  functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
transition.duration = 1.0f;
transition.type =  @"cube";
transition.subtype = @"fromRight";
[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];

forgotLoginViewController = [[ForgotLoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ForgotLoginViewController" bundle:Nil];
[self.view addSubview:forgotLoginViewController.view];
```

it does? My Viewcontrollers and tabbar are implemented in appdelegate like the below

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                         initWithRootViewController:viewController2];


self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController1, navController];
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I am an idiot I didn't tell the VC in the appDelegate to be a Navigation Controller. All working now! I.e. UINavigationController *navController2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                         initWithRootViewController:viewController1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am an idiot I didn't tell the VC in the appDelegate to be a Navigation Controller. All working now! I.e. UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];